# Stacking Arrays in Numpy: Different behaviors between UNIX and Windows

Tags: python, arrays, windows, unix, numpy

*Note: This is Python 2.7, not Py3*

This is an updated attempt at asking an earlier question. You requested my complete code, and explanation of content, and example output files. I'll try my best to format this well.

This code is meant to take an input file from a fluorometric "plate reader" and convert the readings to DNA concentrations and masses. It then generates an output file organized according to an 8x12 plate scheme (standard for DNA/molecular work). Rows are labeled "A, B, C,...,H" and columns are labeled simply 1 - 12.

Based on user input, arrays need to be stacked to format the output. However, when arrays are stacked in UNIX (and either printed or written to an outfile), **they are limited to the first character**.

In other words, in Windows, if a number in the array is 247.5, it prints the full number. But in a UNIX environment (Linux/Ubuntu/MacOS), it becomes truncated to simply "2". A number that is -2.7 will print normally in Windows, but in UNIX simply prints as "-".

The complete code can be found below; *note that the last chunk is the most relevant portion of the code*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

Usage = """
plate_calc.py - version 1.0

Convert a series of plate fluorescence readings
to total DNA mass per sample and print them to 
a tab-delimited output file.

This program can take multiple files as inputs
(separated by a space) and generates a new
output file for each input file.

NOTE: 

1) Input(s) must be an exported .txt file.
2) Standards must be in columns 1 and 2, or 11 
and 12.
3) The program assumes equal volumes across wells.

Usage:

    plate_calc.py input.txt input2.txt input3.txt
"""

import sys
import numpy as np

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    print Usage
else:
#First, we want to extract the values of interest into a Numpy array
    Filelist = sys.argv[1:]
    input_DNA_vol = raw_input("Volume of sample used for AccuClear reading (uL): ")
    remainder_vol = raw_input("Remaining volume per sample (uL): ")
    orientation = raw_input("Are the standards on the LEFT (col. 1 & 2), or on the RIGHT (col. 11 and 12)? ")
    orientation = orientation.lower()
    for InfileName in Filelist:
        with open(InfileName) as Infile:
            fluor_list = []
            Linenumber = 1
            for line in Infile: #this will extract the relevant information and store as a list of lists
                if Linenumber == 5:
                    line = line.strip('\n').strip('\r').strip('\t').split('\t')
                    fluor_list.append(line[1:])
                elif Linenumber > 5 and Linenumber < 13:
                    line = line.strip('\n').strip('\r').strip('\t').split('\t')
                    fluor_list.append(line)
                Linenumber += 1
            fluor_list = [map(float, x) for x in fluor_list] #converts list items from strings to floats
            fluor_array = np.asarray(fluor_list) #this takes our list of lists and converts it to a numpy array
```

This portion of the code (above) extracts the values of interest from an input file (obtained from the plate reader) and converts them to an array. It also takes user input to obtain information for calculations and conversions, and also to determine the columns in which standards are placed.

That last part comes into play later, when arrays are stacked - which is where the problematic behavior occurs.

```
        #Create conditional statement, depending on where the standards are, to split the array
        if orientation == "right":
            #Next, we want to average the 11th and 12th values of each of the 8 rows in our numpy array 
            stds = fluor_array[:,[10,11]] #Creates a sub-array with the standard values (last two columns, (8x2))
            data = np.delete(fluor_array,(10,11),axis=1) #Creates a sub-array with the data (first 10 columns, (8x10))

        elif orientation == "left":
            #Next, we want to average the 1st and 2nd values of each of the 8 rows in our numpy array   
            stds = fluor_array[:,[0,1]] #Creates a sub-array with the standard values (first two columns, (8x2))
            data = np.delete(fluor_array,(0,1),axis=1) #Creates a sub-array with the data (last 10 columns, (8x10))

        else:
            print "Error: answer must be 'LEFT' or 'RIGHT'"

        std_av = np.mean(stds, axis=1) #creates an array of our averaged std values

        #Then, we want to subtract the average value from row 1 (the BLANK) from each of the 8 averages (above)
        std_av_st = std_av - std_av[0]

        #Run a linear regression on the points in std_av_st against known concentration values (these data = y axis, need x axis)
        x = np.array([0.00, 0.03, 0.10, 0.30, 1.00, 3.00, 10.00, 25.00])*10 #ng/uL*10 = ng/well
        xi = np.vstack([x, np.zeros(len(x))]).T #creates new array of (x, 0) values (for the regression only); also ensures a zero-intercept (when we use (x, 1) values, the y-intercept is not forced to be zero, and the slope is slightly inflated)
        m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(xi, std_av_st)[0] # m = slope for future calculations

        #Now we want to subtract the average value from row 1 of std_av (the average BLANK value) from all data points in "data"
        data_minus_blank = data - std_av[0]

        #Now we want to divide each number in our "data" array by the value "m" derived above (to get total ng/well for each sample; y/m = x)
        ng_per_well = data_minus_blank/m

        #Now we need to account for the volume of sample put in to the AccuClear reading to calculate ng/uL
        ng_per_microliter = ng_per_well/float(input_DNA_vol)

        #Next, we multiply those values by the volume of DNA sample (variable "ng")
        ng_total = ng_per_microliter*float(remainder_vol)

        #Set number of decimal places to 1
        ng_per_microliter = np.around(ng_per_microliter, decimals=1)
        ng_total = np.around(ng_total, decimals=1)
```

The above code performs the necessary calculations to figure out the concentration (ng/uL) and total mass (ng) of DNA in a given sample based on a linear regression of the DNA "standards," which can either be in columns 1 and 2 (user input = "left") or in columns 11 and 12 (user input = "right").

```
        #Create a row array (values A-H), and a filler array ('-') to add to existing arrays
        col = [i for i in range(1,13)]
        row = np.asarray(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'])
        filler = np.array(['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-',]).reshape((8,2))
```

The above code creates arrays to be stacked with the original array. The "filler" array is placed based on the user input of "right" or "left" (**the stacking command, np.c_[ ], is seen below**).

```
        #Create output
        Outfile = open('Total_DNA_{0}'.format(InfileName),"w")
        Outfile.write("DNA concentration (ng/uL):\n\n")
        Outfile.write("\t"+"\t".join([str(n) for n in col])+"\n")
        if orientation == "left": #Add filler to left, then add row to the left of filler
            ng_per_microliter = np.c_[filler,ng_per_microliter]
            ng_per_microliter = np.c_[row,ng_per_microliter]
            Outfile.write("\n".join(["\t".join([n for n in item]) for item in ng_per_microliter.tolist()])+"\n\n")
        elif orientation == "right": #Add rows to the left, and filler to the right
            ng_per_microliter = np.c_[row,ng_per_microliter]
            ng_per_microliter = np.c_[ng_per_microliter,filler]
            Outfile.write("\n".join(["\t".join([n for n in item]) for item in ng_per_microliter.tolist()])+"\n\n")
        Outfile.write("Total mass of DNA per sample (ng):\n\n")
        Outfile.write("\t"+"\t".join([str(n) for n in col])+"\n")
        if orientation == "left":
            ng_total = np.c_[filler,ng_total]
            ng_total = np.c_[row,ng_total]
            Outfile.write("\n".join(["\t".join([n for n in item]) for item in ng_total.tolist()]))
        elif orientation == "right":
            ng_total = np.c_[row,ng_total]
            ng_total = np.c_[ng_total,filler]
            Outfile.write("\n".join(["\t".join([n for n in item]) for item in ng_total.tolist()]))
        Outfile.close
```

Finally, we have the generation of the output file. This is where the problematic behavior occurs.

Using a simple print command, I found that the stacking command numpy.c_[ ] is the culprit (NOT the array writing command).

*So it appears that* numpy.c_[ ] *does not truncate these numbers in Windows, but will limit those numbers to the first character in a UNIX environment.*

What are some alternatives that might work on both platforms? If none exists, I don't mind making a UNIX-specific script.

Thank you all for your help and your patience. Sorry for not providing all of the necessary information earlier.

The images are screenshots showing proper output from Windows and what I end up getting in UNIX (I tried to format these for you...but they were a nightmare). I have also included a screenshot of the output obtained in the terminal when I simply print the arrays "ng_per_microliter" and "ng_total."[image: Expected Output]
[image: UNIX Output]
[image: Printed Arrays (UNIX Terminal)]

Comment: You went in the wrong direction.  Make the question and example more compact, focusing on the issue at hand, not bigger and harder to follow.  This looks like a formatting issue.  Are values like `ng_per_microliter` and `ng_total` correct?   I assume they are arrays with shape and dtype.

Comment: In my defense, that is why I broke up the code, and I had been asked for this by a previous commenter.

Answer (score 0):

> Using a simple print command, I found that the stacking command numpy.c_[ ] is the culprit (NOT the array writing command).
>
> So it appears that numpy.c_[ ] does not truncate these numbers in Windows, but will limit those numbers to the first character in a UNIX environment.

Illustrate these statements in simple examples.  `np.c_[]` should not be doing anything different.

In Py3, where the default string type in unicode. And numpy 1.12

```
In [149]: col = [i for i in range(1,13)]
     ...: row = np.asarray(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'])
     ...: filler = np.array(['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-',]).reshape((8,2))
     ...: 
In [150]: col
Out[150]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
In [151]: "\t"+"\t".join([str(n) for n in col])+"\n"
Out[151]: '\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12\n'
In [152]: filler
Out[152]: 
array([['-', '-'],
       ...
       ['-', '-'],
       ['-', '-']], 
      dtype='<U1')
In [153]: row
Out[153]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 
      dtype='<U1')
In [154]: row.shape
Out[154]: (8,)
In [155]: filler.shape
Out[155]: (8, 2)
In [159]: ng_per_microliter=np.arange(8.)+1.23
In [160]: np.c_[filler,ng_per_microliter]
Out[160]: 
array([['-', '-', '1.23'],
       ['-', '-', '2.23'],
       ['-', '-', '3.23'],
      ...
       ['-', '-', '8.23']], 
      dtype='<U32')
In [161]: np.c_[row,ng_per_microliter]
Out[161]: 
array([['A', '1.23'],
       ['B', '2.23'],
       ['C', '3.23'],
         ....
       ['H', '8.23']], 
      dtype='<U32')
```

It is possible that with earlier `numpy` versions that a concatenate of the `U1` (or `S1` in Py2) array with numeric values leaves the dtype at `U1`.  In my example they've been expanded to `U32`.

So if you suspect the `np.c_`, display the result of those (with `repr` if needed)

```
print(repr(np.c_[row,ng_per_microliter]))
```

and track the `dtype`.

for v 1.12 release notes (possibly earlier)

> The astype method now returns an error if the string dtype to cast to is not long enough in “safe” casting mode to hold the max value of integer/float array that is being casted. Previously the casting was allowed even if the result was truncated.

This might come into play when doing concatenate.

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have specified that this is not Py3, it's Python 2.7. I'll explore the behavior further (when I have access to my Ubuntu machine) and come back!

Comment: When I use the repr command, it looks like concatenating the two arrays does leave the entire array at dtype = '|S1'. Are there any ways around this?

Comment: I've been checking dtypes at various steps along the way. The initial array (ng_per_microliter, for example) is 'float64'. But when either my "filler" or "row" arrays are combined with the initial array, the entire dtype is converted to '|S1'.

Comment: So the arrays hold a single character. We'd have to dig around in version 'whats new' lists or SO questions to find out when this was corrected.  Casting the numeric array to something like `S10` before concatenation might help.

Comment: What's the numpy version on the problem system (and on the other as well)?

Comment: I'll have to check around for that info, but a friend for whom the script was not working (he is on a Mac) now has it working after he updated his version of numpy to 1.12 (from 1.6). So you were totally right about that!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of user hpaulj, I've figured out that this isn't an issue with different behavior between operating systems and environments. It's more than likely due to users having different versions of numpy.

The concatenating of arrays automatically converted 'float64' dtypes to 'S1' (to match the "filler" arrays ('-') and "row" arrays ('A','B', etc.)).

Newer versions of numpy - specifically, v 1.12.X - seem to allow the concatenation of arrays without this automatic conversion.

I'm still not sure of a way around this issue in older versions of numpy, but it should be a simple matter to advise folks to upgrade their version for full performance. :)

Comment: It is clear that you have put a lot of time and effort into this question and answer.  So I am going to ask that you take a couple of moments to see the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines on after someone answers your question.  On SO the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  On your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  The little check mark and the up arrow is the only 'pay' guys like @hpaulj get for spending so much time helping us.